# How to scroll to selected row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with PageSize = 20 (20 rows) but it can show only 10 rows without a vertical scrollbar appearing.

My problem is that when a postback occurs, it jumps to top row of the grid even though I selected a different row. I would like to scroll to the selected row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`  in your page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback ="true"%>
```

Another way, use a scrollTop method of the DIV that wraps your GridView:

```
private void ScrollGrid()
{
    int intScrollTo = this.gridView.SelectedIndex * (int)this.gridView.RowStyle.Height.Value;
    string strScript = string.Empty;
    strScript += "var gridView = document.getElementById('" + this.gridView.ClientID + "');\n";
    strScript += "if (gridView != null && gridView.parentElement != null && gridView.parentElement.parentElement != null)\n";
    strScript += "  gridView.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTop = " + intScrollTo + ";\n";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScrollGrid", strScript, true);
}
```

**EDIT:**
  This won't work for several reasons:

1) if the gridView is inside a NamingContainer control, like a Panel, because the Id on the client side won't be the `ClientId`. You need to use the `UniqueId` of teh control instead.

2) you can't trust the row height to calculate the scroll position. If the text in any column wraps to more than one line, or any row contains something higher than the style, the size of the row will be different

3) different browsers can have different behaviors. You're better of using jQuery `scrollTop()` and `scroll()` functions. To use them, you must use `scrollTop` on client side and set the value of a `HiddenControl` that can be read on server side to reset the position. You can't get the height of the rows in the browser until they are rendered on client side.

Comment: A solution along those lines, using a hidden input with runat="server", is described here http://microsoftmiles.blogspot.com/2006/11/maintaining-gridview-scroll-position-in.html  Although this requires ASP.NET AJAX

Answer (score 1):

This code in the RowDataBound event handler for the gridview worked for me:

```
protected void dgv_usersRowDatabound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == intEditIndex)
    {
        DropDownList drpCategory = e.Row.FindControl("drpCategory") as DropDownList;
        drpCategory.Focus();
    }
 }
```

The Gridview contains a dropdownlist in each row as an EditItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, and required no ASP.NET AJAX, UpdatePanel or cookie, and a lot less JavaScript than other solutions I've seen.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnScroll" value="0" />
<div style="height:600px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll">
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myGridView" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
...
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Then

```
protected void myGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //if(gr != null) gr.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Focus(); // Only works on an editable cell

    hdnScroll.Value = (myGridView.SelectedIndex * (int)myGridView.RowStyle.Height.Value).ToString();
}
```

Finally back in the .aspx, to run upon postback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  document.getElementById('<%=myGridView.ClientID%>').scrollTop = $('#hdnScroll').val();
});
```