# Scroll to GridView selected row

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a GridView with fixed header and 10 rows that can be updated new rows by users.
 In the GridView I show only 3 rows and vertical scrollbar.

After a user selects any row on the GridView (the postback occurs), I want to scroll it to the selected row.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working with `winform`?

Comment: @X-TECH - I am thinking not `WinForms`, but rather `WebForms`, as there is a reference to "postback" in the question.

Comment: @Cass 5 - update your question to include the correct tags (`asp.net`, `webforms`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `winform`, you need to set

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Comment: No, I am using webform and I used already "dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;" but I can't use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex ...

Comment: @Cass5 Loot at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512937/how-to-scroll-to-selected-row-in-gridview

Comment: I already use this method ... but (this.gridView.RowStyle) I have error in this one.. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

This is something I came up with to solve this. Its by no means perfect as Im just a noob at JavaScript. Any and all edits are welcome.

First of all ...be aware that

> "Any server controls that appear within the naming container have
>   their rendered id value prefixed with the ID of the naming container
>   control."

From  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

**In a nutshell...you have a hidden field to save the value of the top of the scroll box...and set it back to that value on pageload. All code in JavaScript.**

1: Create hidden field.

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnScrollTop" runat="server" value="0" />
```

2:Update the hidden field with the value of the top of the window (this.scrollTop). This is done via the onscroll attribute. This div will scroll because of `overflow: auto;`. Also notice the name "MainContent_hdnScrollTop".
On the `<aps:Content>` tag (not shown) I have the `ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"`
so you may need to change the name accordingly. Check the names generated on the rendered page.

```
     <div id="divScroll" style="vertical-align: top; height: 550px; overflow: auto; width: 950px;"
        onscroll="$get('MainContent_hdnScrollTop').value = this.scrollTop;">
```

3: You might have to add the scriptmanager control. Your only allowed one. I had a MasterPage that had it already.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" />
```

4: The javascript that set the top of the divScroll to the hidden field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

    function pageLoaded(sender, args)
    {
        try {
            $get("divScroll").scrollTop = $get("MainContent_hdnScrollTop").value;
        }
        catch(err) { return;}
    }
</script>
```